# Interactive Chart with MS Chart Control VB

Tags: vb.net, charts, mschart

Hi I'am currently creating a Chart to and img and display it in view. But I would like to make it a little more interactive ... eg. when user put mose over point (in point chart) he can see the values of this point.

Here I create and image of an chart

```
Function GenerateChart(id As Integer, width As Integer, height As Integer) As ActionResult

    ' Creating chart
    Dim chart = New Chart()
    Dim area = New ChartArea()
    Dim series = New Series()

    chart.Width = width
    chart.Height = height

    ' Adding Series to the Chart
    chart.Series.Add("ValueSeries")
    chart.Series("ValueSeries").XValueMember = "Date"
    chart.Series("ValueSeries").YValueMembers = "Value"
    chart.Series("ValueSeries").ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point
    'chart.Series("ValueSeries1").AxisLabel = "Label"

    ' Getting data for series
    chart.DataSource = GetDataForChart(id)
    chart.DataBind()

    chart.ChartAreas.Add(New ChartArea())

    ' Saving chart as file
    Dim returnVal = New MemoryStream()
    chart.SaveImage(returnVal)

    'Return adress for file
    Return File(returnVal.GetBuffer(), "image/png")
End Function
```

are there any special properties that i may add to make it interactive ? And if I add them maybe I should return something diffrant than an image ?\

EDIT 1

I have read about tool tips .... but you have to set each tooltip for each series value and still i am not sure if tooltips works when you save chart as img but 'll try it

Comment: This is not highcharts related.

Comment: Why are you creating an image? Why not just display the chart itself?

Comment: ok so i make the function to return chart and how to display this chart? with html.action ? oh i forgot to add this is MVC based app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Chart.HitTest method together with the MouseMove event to check for the mouse being over a datapoint. Here is an example

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim ToolTipProvider As New ToolTip

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For i = 1 To 20
            Chart1.Series(0).Points.AddXY(i, i ^ 2)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Chart1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Chart1.MouseMove
        Dim h As Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.HitTestResult = Chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)
        If h.ChartElementType = DataVisualization.Charting.ChartElementType.DataPoint Then
            ToolTipProvider.SetToolTip(Chart1, h.Series.Points(h.PointIndex).XValue & " x " & h.Series.Points(h.PointIndex).YValues(0))
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

It first performs a HitTest and assigns the result to the variable `h`.
The property ChartElementType of the HitTestResult defines what elementtype is located at the given coordinates. If it is a datapoint a corresponding tooltip with the coordinates is assigned to the chart.

[image]

If you do it in a temporary image you need to perform the HitTest in your method and draw the tooltip on the image. I don't know why you do it this way, but making an image interactive is not easily done.

Comment: ok so now if you can help me - i will change function to return a chart value, how to display it later in view with razor? html.render or something similar?

Comment: @JakubWisniewski I have no idea what you mean. Open a new question about the topic and describe in detail what platform you are using and what you are trying to achieve. The question here had nothing to do with displaying a chart in some web application.

Comment: Ok - sory for all the inconvenience ... and thanks for reply :)

Comment: @JakubWisniewski No inconvenience at all. It's just the principle of SO to not mix different questions together that much. You're welcome.