# How to build a chart from points received from machine through serial port?

Tags: vb.net

Converting points to chart

I got data from machine through serial port. How do I convert it to a chart.Below is my data

```
WBC graph
Scale(fl):  400
Channels:   256
WMarker1:   11
WMarker2    40
WMarker3:   70
Points: 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5   7   9   12  17
        22  29  37  48  61  78  97  119 141 163 183 200 216 229 239 248
        253 254 252 247 237 225 211 197 182 168 154 142 131 119 108 97  
        87  77  69  62  57  52  47  43  39  36  32  30  29  28  27  27  
        26  26  26  26  25  25  25  25  25  26  26  27  27  28  28  29  
        30  30  31  32  34  35  37  38  39  40  41  41  42  43  45  46  
        46  47  46  45  44  43  42  41  41  40  40  40  41  42  44  45  
        47  47  48  48  47  46  45  44  43  42  41  40  39  39  39  39  
        39  38  37  37  36  36  35  35  34  34  34  34  34  34  33  32
        31  29  28  27  25  24  23  22  21  21  21  21  21  21  21  20  
        20  19  18  18  17  16  16  15  15  14  14  13  12  11  10  9   
        9   9   9   9   9   8   7   7   6   6   6   6   6   5   5   5
        5   5   5   5   5   5   4   4   3   3   3   2   2   2   2   1   
        1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   
        1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   
        1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: what kind of chart do you want to make?

Comment: i want to make an area chart

Comment: What have your tried? How have you stored your data?

Comment: my data is comming in form of text,i want to store data as abinary in database.i tried to do it in chart control but i didnot success

Comment: i converted that points to listbxitems and added theim to axis y  but its not giving me the expected chart

Comment: Instead of trying to do it all in one program, how about exporting data to a CSV file as text and charting it in EXCEL?

Comment: If you tried something, you need to show it. To add data to a chartcontrol, create a [Series](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.series?view=netframework-4.8) and add your points to it. Then add your series to a `ChartArea`on the control

Comment: @kunif, that seems way less user friendly

Comment: thanks knuif.Iam reciving the data in textbox as text how i convert it to csv?

Comment: i convert it to csv but .i could did it by making that items arrnged into listbox and added that items to series axis y

Comment: It depends on what perspective you want to view the data from. Do you want to make a set of 256 numbers into a single figure, or analyze changes and relationships between multiple 256 numbers, or combine them with some other data? For example, an area chart is [something like this](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/area-chart.html), but if you don't think about how the acquired data fits this figure, you can't draw it.

Comment: the gram should be like that.with the deferance of scale from 200 to 400.here is the link to gram.http://www.mediafire.com/view/dcaei05625idbwl/ice_screenshot_20190903-151243.png

Answer (score 1):

For example, these articles will be helpful.
[Getting started with .NET Charts](https://www.i-programmer.info/programming/uiux/2756-getting-started-with-net-charts.html)
[How to draw continuous line graph in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32047375/9014308)
[Interactive Chart with MS Chart Control VB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24955908/9014308)

References to the following two should be added for the new project/solution:

```
System.Text
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting
```

Assume that the following two controls from the toolbox have been added to the form window:
Assume that TextBox contains the text of the content described in the question.

```
Chart Control
TextBox Control
```

If you paste the following program into a button click event handler and execute it, you can display the diagram.
By the way, the conversion process from `TextBox1.Text` to `values1` and from `values1` to `series1` can be shortened if there is already a numeric character string or integer array data.

```
Chart1.Titles.Clear()
Chart1.Titles.Add("WBC graph")

Chart1.ChartAreas.Clear()
Dim area1 As New ChartArea()
area1.AxisX.Title = "Sample Number"
area1.AxisY.Title = "Count"
area1.AxisY.Maximum = 400
area1.AxisY.Minimum = 0
area1.AxisX.Maximum = 256  ' Added if you want to fix the range.
area1.AxisX.Minimum = 0    '
Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(area1)

Dim values1 As String()
values1 = TextBox1.Text.Substring((TextBox1.Text.IndexOf("Points:") + 8)).Split(New String() {" ", "\t", "\r", "\n", vbCrLf, ","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Dim series1 As New Series()
series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
series1.LegendText = "Cell Count"
For Each s In values1
    series1.Points.Add(Integer.Parse(s))
Next

Chart1.Series.Clear()
Chart1.Series.Add(series1)
```

An example of the result.

[image: sample chart result]

---

**In Addition:**
If you do not want to change the X-axis range even when the number of samples is small, you can set the X axis minimum/maximum values to fixed values when setting the `area1` property.
Add to the source.

Comment: if i get the  Y point in the following form ,  and  the  x axis values 80 points 0,7,17,16,10,6,4,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,12,2,3,4,5,9,14,19,29,40,49,58,73,90,107,120128,129,126,127,131,127,116,106,100,96,90,81,78,78,74,6966,63,60,59,57,55,51,48,44,38,34,32,28,24,19,1715,12,10,8,6,6,6,4,4,4,2,2,3,2,2,3